# реализовать кнопку "Назад" в библиотеке aiogram?

Tags: python, python-3.x, aiogram

В боте для телеграм получилось много клавиатур (ReplyKeyboardMarkup). Нужно как-то определить, какая из этих клавиатур сейчас активна. Есть вариант смотреть на предыдущие сообщения, или же создать в БД для каждого пользователя столбец с состоянием клавы. Но нет ли более простого метода? В официальной документации копался, не нашёл, а поиск там работает как-то криво.

Comment: По-моему БД это и так самое простое и логичное

Comment: Ну, я не знаю, это займёт больше времени, чем посмотреть, какая клавиатура на данный момент у пользователя, а БД - это уже полноценный работоспособный костыль. Мне просто интересно, нет ли функции специально для этой задачи.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно, стоит посмотреть в сторону **FSM**, механизм которых уже реализован в aiogram. Это, скорее всего, потребует переписать  некоторую существующую логику, но по вопросу это должно быть то, что нужно.

С помощью **FSM** вы сможете определять текущее состояние диалога с пользователем, изменять его на любое другое и использовать временное хранилище для определения любых других вещей, например, текущей клавиатуры.

В качестве временного хранилища можно использовать просто **ОЗУ** или **Redis**, что будет лучше.
Вот пример из документации: https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/examples/finite_state_machine_example.html

Comment: Благодарю, товарищ! Обязательно почитаю, и выберу для следующих проектов наиболее удобный вариант.